# How to fetch all the send definitions that uses specific HTML block(Reference block)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-definition

The intension is to find all the impacted Send definitions when there is a change in the reference HTML block

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a dependency analysis between various assets. Which is a pretty common and pretty useful thing to have.

Technically, this is a basic looping exercise through a couple of API call results. It obviously helps to understand the relationship between the various APIs and you'll be leveraging both REST and SOAP for "historic" reasons, I guess.

I am making these basic assumptions:

- all emails affected are `template-based emails` here for simplicity.

(assetTypes reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/base-asset-types.html?q=asset%20type)

- You have to do this once per BU.

You can repeat this approach for more than just that type of email / several BUs in similar fashion, but since you mentioned Reference Content, it sure sounds like you are using templates.

- The order of the api calls doesn't strictly matter, I have just given numbers for ease of reference.

**API Call 1**

leverage the content builder / asset API to retrieve template based emails (assetType = 207)

note that this can be a huge result, so there is a pagination included.
You are retrieving a couple megabytes easily, as this returns full HTML for each email.

```
{{restEndpoint}}/asset/v1/content/assets/?$filter=assetType.id%20eq%20207&$pageSize=50&$page=1&$orderBy=modifiedDate%20DESC&$fields=modifiedDate,modifiedBy,views
```

iterate through the result.

you can find the content SLOTS in `items[i].views.html.slots`
for each email, iterate through all slots per email to find `blocks` (one slot can have many blocks).

something like this is one block:

```
                            "blocks": {
                                "tg982aurydk": {
                                    "assetType": {
                                        "id": 223,
                                        "name": "referenceblock"
                                    },
                                    "content": "%%=ContentBlockbyID(\"25140\")=%%",
                                    "design": "HTML CUT FOR READABILITY",
                                    "meta": {
                                        "options": {
                                            "id": 25140,
                                            "assetType": {
                                                "id": 195,
                                                "name": "freeformblock",
                                                "displayName": "Free Form Block"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
```

this way you can determine all **emails** where a specific reference block is included, by customer Key or ID.

Sometimes this is enough, but you might need to know which journeys etc are affected (= which send definitions reference the found emails)

**2 Get all running sendouts**

- typically this means, which triggered sends are live (this includes emails in running journeys)
- plus transactional sends which work differently in the backend

**2a) get all active triggered sends using SOAP API**

example

POST `{{soapEndpoint}}/Service.asmx`

`contentType` = `text/xml`

`SOAPAction` = `"Retrieve"`

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
       <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">;
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>TriggeredSendDefinition</ObjectType>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Description</Properties>
                <Properties>Email.ID</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

sample response with two:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:ced32043-08fa-4e90-abec-1b8935beb43e</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:90ea71bd-6d79-4274-89a8-54ff7b4904a2</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-ace87e14-8458-4227-9071-2d699a64cd2d">
                <wsu:Created>2023-09-26T17:53:39Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2023-09-26T17:58:39Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>2f5f44a4-8333-4396-ba6b-36f4a350b0ec</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
                <Client>
                    <ID>5360xxxxx</ID>
                </Client>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>c7c972aa-6923-xxxx-a463-8c6ef222cf97</CustomerKey>
                <Name>c7c972aa-6923-xxxx-a463-8c6ef222cf97</Name>
                <Description>blabla0</Description>
                <Email>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ID>8146</ID>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                </Email>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
                <Client>
                    <ID>5360xxxxx</ID>
                </Client>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>ebba160b-b8ce-48a7-xxxx-1905fbeb24df</CustomerKey>
                <Name>ebba160b-b8ce-48a7-xxxx-1905fbeb24df</Name>
                <Description>blabla1</Description>
                <Email>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ID>8146</ID>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                </Email>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The Email.ID from this XML response maps to the **legacy ID** from **api call 1**, where you will find the matching ID in `items[i].data.email.legacy.legacyId`

e.g. something like this should be in the results of your api call 1 (somewhere on one of the result pages, remember you might need more than one run of API call 1, leveraging the pagination):

```
 "data": {
                "email": {
                    "options": {
                        "characterEncoding": "utf-8"
                    },
                    "legacy": {
                        "legacyId": 8146,
                        "legacyKey": "0dcc48b1-5b0c-4036-a15a-45eb1f71799b",
                        "legacyType": "email",
                        "legacyCategoryId": 10271
                    }
```

Combining these two results, you have all contentblocks in all emails which are in all active triggered sends.

**2b) Get all running transactional sends**

Transactional sends work differently, they are much newer than the triggered send framework. So you also need get all running transactional sends from the transactional API. This can be done with a GET request:

`GET restEndpoint + "messaging/v1/email/definitions/?$filter=status%20eq%20active"`

`contentType` = `application/json`

`Authorization` = `Bearer + accessToken`

this returns something like:

```
{
    "requestId": "4c025500-2367-4ac4-950f-0cdd226d64dd",
    "definitions": [        
{
            "name": "testTransactional3",
            "definitionKey": "testTransactional3",
            "status": "Active",
            "createdDate": "2023-05-02T07:03:00",
            "modifiedDate": "2023-05-02T07:04:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "transactionalContainer",
            "definitionKey": "transactionalContainer",
            "status": "Active",
            "createdDate": "2023-05-02T08:36:00",
            "modifiedDate": "2023-05-02T08:36:00"
        }
    ],
    "count": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50
}
```

Iterate through the result (again, it's paginated).
For each of these definitions get details with a GET request:

GET `{{restEndpoint}}messaging/v1/email/definitions/testTransactional3`

`contentType` = `application/json`

`Authorization` = `Bearer + accessToken`

example result for one:

```
{
    "requestId": "06944264-3d4c-4665-9d2f-95c447e7feca",
    "name": "testTransactional3",
    "definitionKey": "testTransactional3",
    "definitionId": "614610b7-e9e8-ed11-ba43-f40343e86f50",
    "description": "testTransactional3",
    "classification": "Default Transactional",
    "status": "Active",
    "createdDate": "2023-05-02T07:03:00",
    "modifiedDate": "2023-05-02T07:04:00",
    "content": {
        "customerKey": "TestJL1111"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "list": "All Subscribers - 8037",
        "autoAddSubscriber": true,
        "updateSubscriber": false
    },
    "options": {
        "trackLinks": true
    },
    "journey": {
        "interactionKey": "76ef4a1c-c4de-42e8-b919-5847c952c446"
    }
}
```

`content.CustomerKey` from this result maps to `items[i].customerKey` from the result of **API call 1**:

```
{
    "count": 191,
    "page": 4,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {},
    "items": [
    ....,
        {
            "id": 17110,
            "customerKey": "TestJL1111",
            "assetType": {
                "id": 207,
                "name": "templatebasedemail",
                "displayName": "Template-Based Email"
            },

...
```

Combining this, you have all contentblocks in all emails which are in all active transactional sends.

==
All in all, with this you have emails containing the block in general, plus the info if they are in active  journeys or in active transactional sends.

Comment: This is probably the most thorough answer in [marketing-cloud] tag in 2023. I wish I could upvote it more than once.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. Really helpful